# not a valid iso file error

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, extract, usb-flash-drive

I'm trying this windows 7 usb/dvd download tool that I discovered from ars technica:
http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2009/12/-the-usb-flash-drive.ars

But I don't know why my windows 7 iso file does not work and its saying that its not a valid iso file. What do I do, do you know of other tools that can burn / extract iso file contents to a flash drive?
Except the tool that is always showing up when you search in google, the command prompt one:
http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2009/12/-the-usb-flash-drive.ars/2
A free tool for windows xp or 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [Microsoft's Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool](http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool) which is their tool for putting their ISOs onto a bootable USB stick.

I used it to install Windows 7, worked like a treat.

You can also get a decompresser like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) that will open ISO's, and should help you figure out if the ISO is corrupted.

Comment: the tools which you are saying is exactly the same tool that I mentioned that didn't work.

Comment: Hey you're right. I looked at the link, but since I only saw command-line action I figured it was a different tool.  If it doesn't work, and an ISO-aware decompresser like 7-Zip can't open it, then I'd say the ISO is corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

hmm the official location for the usb tool is http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool so I'm not sure what you downloaded.